# A weird problem on cron this service and system malfunction on apt-update, upgrade and remove. (A mail for analyzing)

Tags: server, apt, cron, email

There is a problem about a service cron. It will routinely send a mail to notice the latest update list. I got a weird notice as below. I want someone can parse the reason because of that my system suffer some mystery problems-the "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade" both command in vain and system automatically recovery to recover to original point after reboot. It is confusing why it doesn't have any updates and upgrades after reboot, even shutdown and restart-again. Hereby it is a mail cron service suddenly send to me. My latest "cron" mail was stuck on 7 days ago. According to the mail content, there is a fake-hwclock. I am not sure it is the potential causes. Moreover, I want to use apt-get to remove some service in vein also due to recover to original point after reboot. Wish some feedback and advice. Thanks.

```
/etc/cron.hourly/fake-hwclock:
date: invalid date ‘erl\nBinary: libpadre’
/sbin/fake-hwclock: 33: [: -ge: argument expected
Current system time: 2016-10-12 09:17:01
fake-hwclock saved clock information is in the future: erl
Binary: libpadre
To force the saved system clock backwards anyway, use "force"
```

Comment: You are talking about different things in your question. Please address one thing at a time... for example post output of `sudo apt-get update` command and address that issue in one question and the cron hardware clock in a separate question.

Comment: It is really weird. When I rebooted  the system due to that it suddenly quits out of X window, then I just plugged out the machine because of I use "reboot now -h" in vein with some "Fail Notification." The cause made the sudden quitting out of X window-I don't exactly affirm. Before this, I just execute the "sudo service cron stop" and then it just quit of X window. It is so weird. Now, I have rebooted the machine. But, I can't fetch the mail as above content showing. Now, I have to be in the same matters, apt-update, upgrade and remove in vein. Is it a complication symptom on this?

Comment: The mail content is disappear when I reboot machine. It is so weird.

Comment: Meanwhile, it is unlimited loop I face. I mean that I update->upgrade->reboot and then there are back to the original point-what I have upgrade package it is still not to be upgraded. This may be two problem. But, if I remove the package, after reboot, it is still on there. I don't know why the apt-get has this matter. I have been using aptitude to execute. They are the same result wether aptitude or apt-get's method is.